# How to found a cause of memory leak at Windows Phone 8.1 Xaml app?

Tags: c#, xaml, memory-leaks, windows-phone-8.1, profiler

I have found a memory leak in my app and try to fix it. But unfortunately I can't find a cause of the leak. Please see to the screenshot, I got it by the visual studio profiler. I don't see any path to root, but a TracksViewModel alive!

How can I find a cause of the leak?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I can see there is cycle link in `TracksViewModel`.
I guess there is some complicated lambda and lambda EventHandlers

Also you should unsubscribe from all events (PropertyChanged for ex) when VM is not needed anymore. Also you can try some kind of WeakEventHandler if there is no chance to unsubscribe.

Comment: Your are right the cycle link is a lambda used by command to invoke action but it used in all my view models and allows GC to release it .